# Invalid prop children in Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been learning React for the past several weeks.
First developed a simple Chat with plain React, and now I started integrating Redux into my app.

I added a simple Action, a matching Reducer (along with a root reducer) and a Store.
I then reached the part where I need to use the Provider from the react-redux library:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import ConfigureStore from './Store/ConfigureStore';
import Routes from './Routes';

const store = ConfigureStore();
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}
            routes={Routes} />,
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App compiles fine, but I receive the following errors in console:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement.
>       in Provider

and

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

I'm using the React Create App as a starter kit.

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/CodeJjang/react-sample-project/tree/feature/add-redux/client).

Comment: You have a ``,`` after ``<Router history={browserHistory} routes={Routes} />``. Try removing that?

Comment: @iamnat I was scatching my head for like 2 hours, reading almost everything related in google... Thanks. Please make an answer and I'll choose it. Can't believe I missed such small thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a `,` after `<Router history={browserHistory} routes={Routes} />`

Try removing it?

Answer (score 9):

The same error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array`
>   supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement.
>
> Uncaught Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React
>   element child.

Occurs to me in writing Provider with this format:

```js
<Provider store={store}> <App4Connected /> </Provider>
```

instead the following works correctly:

```js
<Provider store={store}>
    <App4Connected />
</Provider>
```

Comment: jsx is white space sensitive. I believe `Provider` had two text children.

Answer (score 1):

To me writing in this format was throwing error:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}> <App /> </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But this works fine:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}> 
        <App /> 
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));
```